# Ambiguous use of observe firebase DB

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

I really cannot get what is wrong?
I'm trying to load some settings data from firebase `Settings` node. Same code for other nodes in other functions work but this one is ambiguous. Why?

```
var ref:FIRDatabaseReference!  //Global variable

     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.mapView.delegate = self

            if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {

                locationManager.delegate = self
                locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
                locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
                locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

              //  monitorRegion()

            } else {

                // Alert to enable location services on iphone first
            }

            ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: "https://*******.firebaseio.com/")
            //The error is here
            ref.child("Settings").child("service_types").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in

            }


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

Comment: The error is on line `ref = ..` or `ref.child("Settings")`

Comment: @Dravidian ref.child("Settings")

Comment: Check out @ronatory answer? And update your Question with the actual error

Comment: Any updates? @KeghamK.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Change this:

```
ref.child("Settings").child("service_types").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in

}
```

to this:

```
ref.child("Settings").child("service_types").observe(.value, with: { snapshot in

})
```

See also [firebase documentation section Listen for value events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write)

Answer (score 2):

You could write your call something like this:

```
ref
  .child("Settings")
  .child("service_types")
  .observe(.value) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) in
    // your code
  }
```

or

```
ref
  .child("Settings")
  .child("service_types")
  .observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
    // your code
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

this function for me:

```
ref.child("Settings").child("service_types").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) -> Void in
    //your code
}
```