# Ambiguous use of "observe" (Swift Compiler Error)

Tags: swift, firebase, ios11

I am trying to load messages from Firebase but its telling me "Ambiguous use of observe"

Please help...new to IOS

```
 func fetchMessages(){
    let messageDB = Database.database().reference().child("Messages")


    messageDB.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String,String>
        let message = Message()
        message.messageBody = snapshotValue["MessageBody"]!
        message.sender = snapshotValue["Sender"]!
        self.messageArray.append(message)
        self.configureTableView()
        self.messageTableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40057276/ambiguous-use-of-observe-firebase-db. Seems that the issue is `.observe.(childAdded)` should be `.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot`

Comment: This worked! Thank you @JenPerson