# " Ambiguous use of 'observe" on Swift - still could find out what went wrong

Tags: swift, firebase

This is my first time asking a question on Stackoverflow and I am also very new to Swift, the language I am learning. So please forgive me if my questions is not as precise as I hope it will be. I am currently following a tutorial from Udemy and the following code something I could not figure out whats wrong :

```
func retrieveMessages(){

    let messageDB = Database.database().reference().child("Messages")

    // have to observe this database to act when new messages are added


    messageDB.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
            let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String,String>

            let text = snapshotValue["MessageBody"]!
            let sender = snapshotValue["Sender"]!

            print(text, sender)
        }
    }
}
```

xcode flag an error on the line :

> messageDB.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in" with the poor
>   message : "Ambiguous use of 'observe'

I hope somebody can help me solve the problem. And baby steps please cause I am very very new to all these. Thank you so much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ambiguous use of observe firebase DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40057276/ambiguous-use-of-observe-firebase-db)

Comment: As a first step when you encounter something like that, take the verbatim error you're getting and dump it in Google. I found a question very similar to yours with a solution posted on SO.

Comment: `messageDB.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in`?

Answer (score 0):

What happened to the `with:`? Change

```
messageDB.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in
    // other stuff
}
```

to

```
messageDB.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
    // other stuff
})
```

Comment: Hi Matt, this for reply. I  tried, and yes the error message disappear. But now I have another problem, in the code I am suppose to print out the "text" and "sender". But nothing happens when I run it. Do you have any idea whats wrong? (sorry maybe I should ask this question in a new post. Apologies)